# Prove that the roots of cyclotomic polynomial $\Phi_{p-1}(x) \equiv 0 (mod~p)$ are exactly the primitive roots mod p

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, primitive-roots, cyclotomic-polynomials

$p$ is a prime, and $\Phi_{p-1}(x)$ denote the cyclotomic polynomial of order $p-1$. And I want to show the following:

$g$ is a solution of the congruence $\Phi_{p-1}(x) \equiv 0 (mod~p)$ if and only if $g$ is a primitive root (mod p)

that is:

$\Phi_{p-1}(g) \equiv 0 (mod~p) \iff g$ is a primitive root (mod p)

Here is some properties about cyclotomic polynomial:

${\textstyle \prod_{d|n}^{}}\Phi_{d}(x) = x^n-1\tag{1}$

$\Phi_{n}(x) = {\textstyle \prod_{d|n}^{}}(x^d-1)^{\mu(n/d)}\tag{2}$

$\mu(x)$ is the Möbius inversion formula

Comment: In general, when $p\nmid n$, the roots of $\Phi_n$ in $\mathbb F_p$ are going to be precisely the elements of order $n$ in $\mathbb F_p^\times$. This shouldn't be too hard for you to prove by induction.

Comment: @Wojowu Could you give me some tips beacuse I have tried the induction but I failed.

Comment: Firstly show that $x^n-1$ has no double roots. After you do that, note that if a root $a$ has order $d<n$, then $d\mid n$, and so $\Phi_d(a)=0$, and as there are no double roots, this implies $\Phi_n(a)\neq 0$.

Comment: I didn't write it in the cleanest possible way, but [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2009118/11619) should help you.

Comment: @Wojowu Thanks you so much and I wonder the roots are whether congruence roots or the normal roots?

Comment: $\Phi_{p-1}$ divides $x^{p-1}-1$ and it is coprime with each $x^d-1,d| p-1,d< p-1$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thanks for comments but I don't know why $a$ is also a roots of  $\Phi_\ell(x)$ when $\ell\mid p-1$

Comment: @reuns Thanks for your comments and could you give me more details about the coprime between two phynomial?

Comment: My argument in the linked thread was not clearly written at all. I tried to edit it. May be somebody else said it better :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen It is such kind of you and I am reallly appreciated!